# OpenSessionInterceptor for Spring-Hibernate-AOP context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-aop, transactional

I'm developing a web app application with spring 4, jsf 2 and hibernate 5. To manage transactional operation in hibernate in web context, i use the OpenSessionInViewFilter in **web.xml**.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My spring context configuration about dataSource is:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6DataSource">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
                <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 5 Annotation SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />     
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>org.dummy.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>             
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.flushMode">COMMIT</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.flushMode">COMMIT</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.dummy.persistence" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

**UPDATED**
My application listener is

```
@Component
public class SimplePopulator implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    protected UserFacadeService userFacadeService;

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        try {
            ////sessionFactory.set
            //Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            //session.beginTransaction();
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            UserAccount account1 = userFacadeService.createUserAccount("testAA", "testAA", "User Dummy", "dummy@email.org");
            //session.save(account1);
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            System.out.println(userFacadeService.existsAccount("test"));

            //session.getTransaction().commit();
            //session.close();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

When i launch the application, on application listener execution i receive the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:692)
    at org.abubu.whisper.persistence.impl.AbstractRepository.getCurrentSession(AbstractRepository.java:46)
    at org.abubu.whisper.persistence.impl.UserAccountRepositoryImpl.findByUsername(UserAccountRepositoryImpl.java:26)
```

I need to use **transaction** in spring context event listener, so i can not use **OpenSessionInViewFilter** because it works only for web request. I think i can use **OpenSessionInterceptor** with AOP, but i did not find any example about use it.

How can i use **OpenSessionInterceptor** with AOP?

Comment: OpenSessionInView has nothing to do with transactions...

Comment: I'm quite sure you're wrong. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html

Comment: I'm quite sure I'm not, read the first line of the documentation you point to that is the purpose of the `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.  The purpose of the open session in view is only to keep a session open so that you don't get lazy loading exceptions... It has nothing to do with transactions or starting/ending transactions... If you need a transaction in a listener just make it transactional...

Comment: Deinum, i'm sorry, I did not want to be rude. I updated the answer to better explain my problem.

Comment: If you get this exception it has nothing to do with the use of an open session in view filter. It basically points that you have setup transactions wrong. Why are you using `mode="aspectj"` this implies that you are using load or compile time weaving to apply your aspects, however the `<aop:aspects-autoproxy/>` suggests otherwise...

Comment: Thank Deinum, i change annotation-driven mode to proxy and now it works!!